# An interview riddle: probably sha decrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I recently had an interview for PHP developer, and the company said they'll send me a small project to prove my programing ability.
I got this email :

> Hi,
>
> So this is what we has for you:
>
> Find the enigma behind those numbers:
>   "616d5567633356706379423162694272615778735a5849675a57346755456851"
>   (tip: you have to be a killer in php to find the solution)
>
> Have a nice weekend.

As far as I can tell, this is an SHA encrypt and to solve it I need to calculate rainbow tables for all possible SHA algorithms in PHP aka sha256, sha384, sha512...
I checked few on-line tools to decrypt strings. 
like : http://rainbowtables.it64.com/ but no results

Isn't it a huge mission ?
Am I right? What's your solution?

Comment: I'd apply somewhere else. That's a stupid interview question, IMO.

Comment: the company obviously does not care strongly about correct grammar either

Comment: It is 20 monkeys trying to write a Shakespeare sonnet

Comment: It's not a SHA. See my answer.

Comment: Also note `sha` is not an encryption (or none of the versions I know of) and it can not be decrypted. It is a hash.

Comment: I don't think having a nice weekend is that huge of a mission.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Heh. "I had a nice weekend, as directed! The enigma behind those numbers is that you think random puzzle-solving is indicative of programming ability."

Comment: @ceejayoz Maybe it's a random puzzle-solving company.

Answer (score 9):

`616d5567633356706379423162694272615778735a5849675a57346755456851`

Is a hex encoding of ASCII characters:

`amUgc3VpcyB1biBraWxsZXIgZW4gUEhQ`

Which is base64 for:

`je suis un killer en PHP`

Comment: Thanks . Thats great .
I thought about hex 2 ascii but not to base64 it ...

Comment: I was gonna comment that this is really missing the point of an interview question, but then I remembered about 90% of my job is Googling stuff anyways.